# map json schema to c# model with NJsonSchema throws System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, json, jsonschema, njsonschema

Im trying to convert really simple json schema to my c# model using nuget from [this link](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema)

Im using example code from the github repo such as:

```
var schema = """{"$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#","title":"Person","type":"object","additionalProperties":false,"required":["FirstName","LastName"],"properties":{"FirstName":{"type":"string"},"LastName":{"type":"string"}},"definitions":{}}""";
   
var generator = new CSharpGenerator(schema);
var file = generator.GenerateFile("mytest"); // on this line I got an exception
Console.WriteLine(file);
Console.ReadLine();
```

this is my json schema:

Notice: Im using .net 7 , you can notice that Im using tripple string in order to accept json with double quotes.

**Exception that I get:**

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'NJsonSchema.JsonSchema'.'

What I did wrong here?

Comment: Why you don't post your question at this library site? There are already thousands custom json libraries,  why we should try every one of them?

Answer (score 0):

```
using NJsonSchema;
using NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration.CSharp;

var schema = ...
var jsonSchema = await JsonSchema.FromJsonAsync(schema);
var generator = new CSharpGenerator(jsonSchema);
var file = generator.GenerateFile("mytest");
Console.WriteLine(file);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**